# bash quote problem

Tags: bash, scripting

http://pastebin.com/GvZVS7a7

help please

**Edit**

Here's the code from the pastebin:

```
d=`echo \"$1\"`
echo $d

#command run
./command 2

#expected output
"2"
```

Comment: Please post your code here, rather than at pastebin.

Comment: i am losing some chars if i post here , thats why i used pastebin ?

Comment: i found problem inside function $1 is not effective ! thanks for help

Comment: Your code pastes fine here, as mkucharz's answer demonstrates. Voting to close, as your followup comment indicates that the code you posted is not actually the code you're using. (P.S. A shell function takes arguments just like a command does. If you want to pass your script's arguments into it, invoke it as `my_function "$@"` from the script.)

Comment: It helps if you are specific about how the actual behavior differs from what you expect (or, when appropriate, include specific error messages). Most people who fail to do this at least include the phrase "doesn't work" in their question. You failed to even do that. To format code here, use the format code button (labeled `101010`) or indent each line with four spaces. For in-line code you can surround it with backticks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it... It works for me:

```
$ cat -> command
d=`echo \"$1\"`
echo $d
$ chmod +x command
$ ./command 2
"2"
$
```

Comment: whats your linux distro, i am using suse , doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
ruffian% cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

d=`echo \"$1\"`
echo $d

ruffian% /bin/bash test.sh 2
"2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command works for me, but [you should use `$()`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) instead of ``` `` ```.

```
d=$(echo \"$1\")
```

However, it's not necessary to use `echo` in the assignment:

```
d=\"$1\"
```

However, on output, you probably want to quote your variable to preserve whitespace:

```
echo "$d"
```